# POST request from Meteor phone app client

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a simple mobile app using Meteor that will send user location data to a geospatial database/server.  I am not sure if what I am trying to do is actually possible with Meteor or if I am doing something incorrectly.

There is no Meteor server component to this, just the client code.  First, I need to get a token from the server using a POST request.  This works when testing the code (meteor run android-device).  I can see the token information.  But it does not work when I build the Android phone app.  I tried multiple ways to get the token (AJAX POST, Meteor Http, and XMLHttpRequest), all of which work when testing.

I have been through Meteor and CORS docs and many other posts regarding similar issues but can't seem to find a resolution.  This is the first time I have worked in this area so I am not sure if I am missing something obvious or if what I am trying to do is not allowed in Meteor in production.

So,

1. Is what I am trying to do not allowed in Meteor phone app (app is not using Meteor server, that is a non-started where I work)?
2. Is this a CORS issue I am not handling properly, even though I can POST when testing?
3. Is there something I need to do while building the Android/iOS app?
4. Is the problem something else?

I'm really not sure what else to look at or how to further troubleshoot.

Thanks for any help!

Here are some (sanitized) code snippets for the POST requests that work while testing if they are helpful.

AJAX:

```
var getToken_ajax = function() {
    var tokenData = {
        username: "theusername",
        password: "thepassword",
        f: 'json',
        expiration: 60,
        client: 'referer',
        referer: window.location.origin
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://<address>:<port>/arcgis/tokens/generateToken",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: tokenData,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //  do something
        }
    });
};
```

XMLHttpRequest:

```
var getToken_XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    var tokenData = "username=theusername&password=thepassword&f=json&expiration=60&client=referer&referer=" + window.location.origin;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https://<address>:<port>/arcgis/tokens/generateToken/';
    var xhrHistoryText;
    var body = tokenData;
    function doPost() {
        if (xhr) {
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChangeHandler;
            xhr.send(body);
        }
        else {
            //  do something
        }
    }
    function stateChangeHandler(evtXHR) {
        // do something
    }
    doPost();
};
```

Comment: Is the browser engine logging any errors anywhere that indicate what’s failing? CORS-related errors for normal web apps get logged to the browser devtools console

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was not a proper certificate in place.  Once in place, POSTing in production worked as expected.